# What happened to Dojo DOH?

Tags: unit-testing, dojo, doh

The Dojo Toolkit used to come with a testing facility called "Doh".  It was in the /utils directory.

Now when you download dojo-release-1.3.2 the /utils directory is nowhere to be found.

Is Doh dead and gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's dead and gone, I'm using it right now to develop code against dojo 1.3.2 and it's working fine.  If you can find it in an older release (as long as it's not too old), you should still be able to use it.

**Edit**

You can find it [here](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/current-stable/dojo-release-1.3.2/util/doh/) in the source...

Comment: Thanks!  It appears there is a lot left out of the "release" including the test subdirectories.

Answer (score 7):

Dojo is packaged two different ways for download and unfortunately it's not terribly clear what these are.  One is a "source" (src) package with all of the unoptimized sources and all of the tools to optimize them, along with tests.  This tends to be quite large.  The plain "release" package is the result of running the build tools against Dojo to produce an optimized set of files.  Because they are not needed to run Dojo and to keep the download size small, tests and tools like DOH are not included.

DOH is actually not dependent on Dojo and should probably be packaged as a separate product.